# Can't create a 2nd membership type within the same membership organisation

Tags: civimember

When we started with Civi 4.2, Membership Types within the same organisation were set to "upsell", ie if you had Membership Type X (OrgY) and opted for Membership Type Z (OrgY) then your single row of membership would change from type X to type Z.

This was most confusing in our use-case and we were delighted to discover that this default behaviour was no longer present when we upgraded to 4.5 (or 4.6, can't be exact here, sorry.)

I am virtually certain that we have observed non-upsell behaviour, ie, purchasing membership Type Z (Org Y) resulted in two lines of membership, type X and type Z.

However, at some indeterminate point in the last 12 months, this became no longer the case.

Now, it is simply not possible for a Contact to purchase a 2nd membership type within the same membership organisation.

In our case, it appears that if a Contact has a membership type X and then goes to create a new membership type Z within the same membership organisation Y, then Civi and Auth.net (our payment provider) will process everything correctly (online confirmation screens, payments correctly setup)... but NOT in the Membership area. A new membership Z will not be created, nor will the existing membership X be updated.

Am I missing something fundamental here? Or has a recent update in 4.6 confounded things?

We're on Drupal 7.43, Civi 4.6.14.

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: For the record, this was the closest I could find in JIRA which implied at that time it was a feature request that never happened. https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15761

Comment: The **online** behaviour has always been to "upsell" an existing current membership rather than create a second membership to the same organisation. (I am not sure what happens for an online transaction if the previous membership has expired.) 

An admin user working through the back-office UI can create a second membership of a different type for the same organisation.  

Neither of those things has changed from 4.4 through to 4.7

Comment: Please test and report back on what happens if a person with membership type X renews their membership of type X and also what happens if a new person takes out a membership of type Z without already having a membership of type X.

Comment: Re your general concern of membership X being "upsold" to membership Z becuase they both belong to Org Y: - We successfully have four different membership types that can be held concurrently by our members. I had to create 4 "organisations" before I could create the membership types, but if you name the the orgs sensibly (eg "Personal member", "Professional journal" etc.) your back office staff should have no problems and as far as the public is concerned they are all just memberships offered by Our Organisation. Possible bug aside, it really is not difficult to manage concurrent memberships.

Comment: Thanks so much for these helpful comments! Regarding testing, as in your third comment, I can confirm that everything works correctly in those situations. It works to renew Membership X, and it works for a new person to purchase a new membership Z if they don't have a membership X.

Comment: So, I guess we can conclude that a bug has crept into our site regarding the upsell process?